# Accessing to TempData From GLOBAL.ASAX

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'am looking for a method to get access and set `TempData` in `GLOBAL.ASAX`

I tried like this but still getting Error on TempData.

`HttpContext.Current.TempData["Passed"] = "1";`

Comment: why would you want to do that? Doesn't sound right.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need a really temp carrier, to the first page load. I need to use it in session on start in global.asax and give special notice to users. etc.

Comment: Why not just put it in `Session_Start`and in the real `Session[]` and then do your check, removing it if you used it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TempData` is a property of the `System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase` class.  Since you are not in a controller, it is not accessible. I would highly doubt you can get at it easily, since the whole chain that sets this up is constructed by the MVC framework.

Since `TempData[]` is backed by the `Session` (i.e. `SessionStateTempDataProvider`) you should be able to insert the value into session and get it out.  This does rely on reading the source code (to find the key used), and definitely isn't supported.

```
var dataKey = "__ControllerTempData";
var dataDict = HttpContext.Current.Session[dataKey] as IDictionary<string,object>;
if (dataDict == null) { 
    /* what do you want to do? add a new IDict<> and put in session? */ 
} else {
    dataDict["Passed"] = 1;
    HttpContext.Current.Session[dataKey] = dataDict;
}
```

***Caveat, untested code!  You WILL need to debug.***

As others have said, what is the reason for doing this? What are you trying to accomplish?  The is probably a much better way to do it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your clear respond.
 But, Error: The name 'currentTemp' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to change one location.  I hope you can see that and fix the issue.  If you want to do something this strange you should be able to debug the basics.  Updated.

Comment: Tested. This works from Application_AcquireRequestState (in BeginRequest: Session is always null)

Answer (score 1):

Thats obviously not working because `HttpContext` does not have any property called `TempData`.

Depending of what you want to achieve, use `HttpContext.Current.Cache` or `HttpContext.Current.Session` for example...